# mount "bad usage"

Tags: mount

Newbie here with Xubuntu 22.04

Trying to mount my NAS with the following command

```
sudo mount -t cifs vers=1.0 //192.168.1.3/share /media/share
```

returns mount:`bad usage`

I can see the NAS share with smbclient

What am I getting wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `vers=1.0` is an option, not a separate parameter. It should be preceded by the `-o` option flag, like this: `-o vers=1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jos,

I put the vers=1.0 as an option and everything is ok now.